# how to complete the original name in helm dired rename

Tags: helm, dired

is it possible to let helm complete the current file name in helm-dired-do-rename? 
It is not convenient if I need to type in a long name only to change a part of it.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can navigate to that file, execute persistent actdion (default is `C-z`) to complete it, then start modifying.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am not sure of what you said. But in dired buffer I navigate to the file, then hit shift+R to rename it, and select it in helm buffer, then Ctrl+Z, nothing happens.

Comment: You can do it this way: run `helm-find-files` (probably you assigned it to< `C-x C-f` on the file you want to rename, press `M-R` to rename then type a new name. If you want to reuse the existing name, press `C-z`.

Answer (score 3):

Actually this is documented in the helm wiki:

To yank the symbol at point from helm-current-buffer (i.e. buffer where a helm command originated):

```
M-n
```

Alternatively, customize helm-yank-symbol-first to enable

```
C-w
```

to always yank the whole symbol on first invocation.